# What is a reliable way to git diff a single uncommitted file against a specific commit?

Tags: git

```
>git diff a23a948 predictor/utils.py
```

This does not show any diff even though I am certain a diff exists.

```
>git diff a23a948:predictor/constants.py predictor/constants.py
fatal: Path 'predictor/constants.py' exists on disk, but not in 'a23a948'.
```

This error message is confusing because the file definitely has existed in the repo long before that commit. Though it was later accidentally deleted.

Comment: `git diff <commit-hash> -- <file>`, for porcelain. Use `git diff-index` for plumbing. In the second command, the error message could be misleading if you're not in the top level of your work-tree; use `<rev>:./predictor/constants.py` to tell Git that you mean it should climb down that far from the top level of the specified commit.

Comment: Check with `git ls-tree -r --full-tree a23a948` if the file actually existed when that commit was recorded.

Comment: @torek: that worked. thank you.

Comment: @alfunx: that too was very helpful. thank you.